# ”Drive-in rally"

Tags: word-meaning

Currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/election-2020-live-updates-obama-130923660.html), a line says,

> Former President Barack Obama steps onto the campaign trail Wednesday with a **drive-in rally** in Philadelphia as Joe Biden and President Donald Trump battle for key swing state Pennsylvania. Obama will speak at 6 p.m. EDT.

I checked such as [**this page,**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drive-in) which says:

> A **drive-in** is a restaurant, cinema, or other commercial place which is specially designed so that customers can use the services provided while staying in their cars.

but I am not sure which definition fits with this bold one or if there may be other meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt the terms “drive-in” and “rally” have ever been combined like this before, but the meaning seems fairly logical.

Normally, political rallies are held in person, usually indoors. I would assume that, due to COVID concerns, they have changed this so that attendees can stay safely isolated in their cars, similar to a drive-in movie rather than going inside a movie theater.

Comment: I think I don't have anything to say anymore if you say "I doubt the terms “drive-in” and “rally” have ever been combined like this before," Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

in this context it means that BO is in Philly for a short time/limited engagement, but his presence will show support to JB's cause, in effect asking his supports to rally for JB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you kindly use less acronyms since I'm not a native speaker?

Comment: @Kentaro - The only "acronyms" here are initials: BO for Barack Obama and JB for Joe Biden. My only problem with this answer is that it doesn't really address your question about the term "drive-in".

Comment: @J.R. Yes, it goes without saying for you, native speaker, but I am sorry I could not understand when I came across BO at first (though I understood later.)

Comment: It's not a "native speaker" thing. It threw me for a moment also.